# PHP Class для работы со стилями CSS

Tags: php

Помогите разобраться, пишу класс который должен формировать и выдавать ссылки на стили. Как это лучше всего организовать?

```
class Styles {
  public $name;

  public
  function __construct($get) {
    $div_class = array(
      'one' => 'one',
      'button' => 'button_statistic',
      'two' => 'two');

    $close = array(
      'div' => '</div>',
      'span' => '</span>'
    );

    if (in_array($get, $div_class))
      $this - > name = '<div class="'.$div_class[$get].
    '">';
    elseif(in_array($get, $close))
    $this - > name = $div_class[$get];

  }
}

$styles = new Styles("two");

echo $styles - > name;
```

Comment: А как вы собираетесь использовать его? Судя по вашему коду, здесь не формируются ссылки, а создается `<div>` с классом, передаваемым в параметры.

Comment: Именно, мне нужно сформировать div с параметром.

Comment: Зачем для этого писать класс?

Comment: У меня сейчас сделано таким странным образом:class Style
{

    var $div = '</div>';

    var $one = '<div class="one">';

    var $gray = ' style="color: gray"';

    var $gray_span = '<span style="color:gray">';

    var $span = '</span>';

    var $middle_class = 'class="middle"';

    var $gray_menu = '<div class="gr_top">'; и тд. Я просто читаю это как например  $style->span; где нужно. как лучше причесать такую работу со стилями?

Answer (score 1):

У вас получился прекраснейший велосипед с квадратными колёсами, управляемый костылями. Вам посоветую так больше не делать, а использовать существующие классы для работы с HTML деревом. Вот, например, [официальная документация](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) или совсем близко к вашей теме на [гитхабе](https://github.com/naomik/htmlgen). Ну и совсем баян - ссылка на англоязычное [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3488373/php-class-to-generate-html)

Comment: А phpQuery тоже подойдет?

Comment: Если кто может привести маленький пример как работать с The DOMDocument class для моей задачи?

Comment: phpQuery не подойдет. Эта библиотека действует в обратную сторону. От HTML дерева до объектов. Вам же нужно от объектов к HTML дереву